# Append changes from database to database history VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Description:
I have a simple worksheet called "database" with the item description, quantity, purchase price, and today's date.

End Goal:
I'd like to create a database history that tracks each in and out entry of the database Worksheet. I tried to insert it into the Database History, however it overwrites the previous data, and I want to track every input made by the same or different users. I've attached images to help you grasp the database concept. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, as I am new to VBA.

[Database worksheet displaying cretia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja2m2.png)[Database History worksheet displaying cretia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NDoE.png)

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
Dim wsDB As Worksheet
Dim WsDBH As Worksheet
Set wsDB = Sheet2
Set WsDBH = Sheet4

With Me
    isSubmit = False
    .lbErr.Caption = ""
    
    'validation checking 
    If .cbName.Value = "" Then
        .lbErr.Caption = "Description cannot be empty"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf .tbDate.Value = "" Then
        .lbErr.Caption = "Date cannot be empty"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf .tbQty.Value = "" Then
        .lbErr.Caption = "Quantity cannot be empty"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf .tbPprice.Value = "" Then
        .lbErr.Caption = "Purchase Price cannot be empty"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf .tbUser.Value = "" Then
        .lbErr.Caption = "User Name cannot be empty"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If .LbQtyAv.Caption = "" Then .LbQtyAv.Caption = 0
    If Int(.LbQtyAv.Caption) < 0 And obOut.Value = True Then
        .lbErr.Caption = "You cannot take more than Qty available"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    isSubmit = True
    'wsDB is sheet 2 Database
    wsDB.Range("A" & frow).Value = .cbName.Value
    wsDB.Range("B" & frow).Value = .LbQtyAv.Caption
    wsDB.Range("C" & frow).Value = .tbPprice.Value
    wsDB.Range("D" & frow).Value = .tbDate.Value

 RW = WsDBH.Range("A" & wsDB.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    WsDBH.Range("A" & RW).Value = .cbName.Value
    WsDBH.Range("B" & RW).Value = tbQty.Text
    WsDBH.Range("C" & RW).Value = .tbPprice.Value
    WsDBH.Range("D" & RW).Value = .tbDate.Value
    WsDBH.Range("E" & RW).Value = .tbUser.Value
 If .obIn.Value = False Then WsDBH.Range("F" & RW).Value = "Out" Else WsDBH.Range("F" & RW).Value = "In"
End With

Call clear

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I tried turning the range function into a cell function, but it didn't work. Maybe I'm refrencing something incorrectly to a point that could lead to a worksheet change in the properties, but I'm having no luck.

```
 RW = WsDBH.Range("A" & wsDB.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Comment: try `RW = WsDBH.Cells(wsDBH.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`